# Remove Selection border in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, border

Hi all I have a screen shot below attached, I have taken that in chrome browser
[image]

actually the blue shaded portion is a input type text . I have to remove completely the border for that, I have removed by css (border:none;) on the normal state and focused state, and it works fine in mozilla, but for chrome it shows a blue selection identification for the same, is there any way remove that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this in the focus state:

```
outline: 0;
box-shadow: none;
```

And add the default border you want. Like `1px solid black`